# Error 1004 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when trying to copy values (Workbook and worksheet explicitly set, no named ranges)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

My problem is stated in the title. The error occurs in the first line with .Copy, but I have had it the same as the second one and received the same error.

I have checked so that the Sheet names are correct, and even copied them straight from the Sheet title in case some weird character sneaked in.

I'll put snippets of code here and then the full code in the end in case the problem is something different.

Declaration:
(I have tried setting it explicitly with Workbooks() but it didn't help)
Dim wb As Workbook

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook' Or  Workbooks("collected.xlsm")
Dim sUser As Worksheet, sExceptions As Worksheet
Set sUser = wb.Sheets("User")
Set sExceptions = wb.Sheets("Exceptions")
```

Copying:

```
sUser.Range(Cells(rS, 1)).Copy Destination:=sExceptions.Range(Cells(Count, 1))
sUser.Range(rS, 11).Copy Destination:=sExceptions.Range(Count, 2)
```

Entire code:

```
Option Explicit

Function FindExceptions()

    ' To run faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Variable def
    Dim Count As Integer

    ' Variable def
    ' Worksheets
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Or Workbooks("collected.xlsm")
    Dim sUser As Worksheet, sVCD As Worksheet, sFullExport As Worksheet
    Set sUser = wb.Sheets("User")
    Set sVCD = wb.Sheets("VCD")
    Set sFullExport = wb.Sheets("FullExport")
    ' r, f, c = Search, Find, Check
    ' For Each rows
    Dim rS As Integer, rF As Integer, rC As Integer
    'Set rS = sUser.Columns("A")
    'Set rF = sVCD.Columns("A")
    'Set rC = sFullExport("B")
    ' Vars used in execution
    'Dim cS As Range, cF As Range, cC As Range
    Dim secId As String, employeeNum As String, FoundVCD As Boolean, FoundFullExport As Boolean


    ' Go through User sheet
    For rS = 2 To sUser.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        secId = sUser.Cells(rS, "A").Value
        employeeNum = sUser.Cells(rS, "K").Value
        ' Search for in VCD
        FoundVCD = False
        For rF = 2 To sVCD.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If sVCD.Cells(rF, "A").Value = secId And sVCD.Cells(rF, "K").Value = employeeNum Then
                FoundVCD = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'Search for in Full Export?
        If FoundVCD = True Then
            FoundFullExport = False
            For rC = 2 To sFullExport.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                If sFullExport.Cells(rC, "B").Value = secId Then
                    FoundFullExport = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If FoundFullExport = False Then
            ' WriteExceptions sUser.Cells(rS, "A").Value, sUser.Cells(rS, "K").Value, sFullExport.Cells(rC, "A").Value, sFullExport.Cells(rC, "D").Value

            ' Worksheet var
            Dim sExceptions As Worksheet
            Set sExceptions = wb.Sheets("Exceptions")

            If Count = Null Or Count = 0 Then
                sExceptions.Cells(1, "A") = "Säk. Id"
                sExceptions.Cells(1, "B") = "Anst. Nr"
                sExceptions.Cells(1, "C") = "Unison Id"
                sExceptions.Cells(1, "D") = "Kort hex"
                Count = 2
            Else
                Count = Count + 1
            End If

            ' secId on col A, employeeNum on col B, unisonId on col C, cardHex on col D
            sUser.Range(Cells(rS, 1)).Copy _
                Destination:=sExceptions.Range(Cells(Count, 1))
            sUser.Range(rS, 11).Copy _
                Destination:=sExceptions.Range(Count, 2)
            sFullExport.Range(rC, 1).Copy _
                Destination:=sExceptions.Range(Count, 3)
            sFullExport.Range(rC, 4).Copy _
                Destination:=sExceptions.Range(Count, 4)
        End If

    Next

    Count = 0

    ' To end settings to run faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Function
```

Comment: you are missing cells inside Range(count,2): Range(Cells(count,2)), or you could use just cells(count,2) too... if by changing these it still doesn't work I'll try with ".PasteSpecial" instead of using "destination:="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing `Range` and `Cells`.

Try

```
        sUser.Cells(rs, 1).Copy _
            Destination:=sExceptions.Cells(count, 1)
        sUser.Cells(rs, 11).Copy _
            Destination:=sExceptions.Cells(count, 2)
        sFullExport.Cells(rC, 1).Copy _
            Destination:=sExceptions.Cells(count, 3)
        sFullExport.Cells(rC, 4).Copy _
            Destination:=sExceptions.Cells(count, 4)
```